# How to simplify this code with for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, simplify

For my school project we are creating a card game, and I have some huge blocks of code that I hardcoded. I am hoping someone is able to see a pattern in the code that I have attached and is able to compact it with for loops.

```
    // set the pointers of the cards in the pyramid
    card [0].setPtrs (card [1], card [2]);
    card [1].setPtrs (card [3], card [4]);
    card [2].setPtrs (card [4], card [5]);
    card [3].setPtrs (card [6], card [7]);
    card [4].setPtrs (card [7], card [8]);
    card [5].setPtrs (card [8], card [9]);
    card [6].setPtrs (card [10], card [11]);
    card [7].setPtrs (card [11], card [12]);
    card [8].setPtrs (card [12], card [13]);
    card [9].setPtrs (card [13], card [14]);
    card [10].setPtrs (card [15], card [16]);
    card [11].setPtrs (card [16], card [17]);
    card [12].setPtrs (card [17], card [18]);
    card [13].setPtrs (card [18], card [19]);
    card [14].setPtrs (card [19], card [20]);
    card [15].setPtrs (card [21], card [22]);
    card [16].setPtrs (card [22], card [23]);
    card [17].setPtrs (card [23], card [24]);
    card [18].setPtrs (card [24], card [25]);
    card [19].setPtrs (card [25], card [26]);
    card [20].setPtrs (card [26], card [27]);

    // set card X coords
    cardCentreX [0] = 800;
    cardCentreX [1] = 800 - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [2] = 800 + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [3] = cardCentreX [1] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [4] = cardCentreX [2] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [5] = cardCentreX [2] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [6] = cardCentreX [3] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [7] = cardCentreX [4] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [8] = cardCentreX [5] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [9] = cardCentreX [5] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [10] = cardCentreX [6] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [11] = cardCentreX [7] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [12] = cardCentreX [8] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [13] = cardCentreX [9] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [14] = cardCentreX [9] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [15] = cardCentreX [10] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [16] = cardCentreX [11] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [17] = cardCentreX [12] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [18] = cardCentreX [13] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [19] = cardCentreX [14] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [20] = cardCentreX [14] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [21] = cardCentreX [15] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [22] = cardCentreX [16] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [23] = cardCentreX [17] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [24] = cardCentreX [18] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [25] = cardCentreX [19] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [26] = cardCentreX [20] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
    cardCentreX [27] = cardCentreX [20] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 28 ; i++)
    {
        cardCentreY [i] = 50;
        if (i == 1 || i == 2)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [0] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
        else if (i >= 3 && i <= 5)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [1] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
        else if (i >= 6 && i <= 9)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [3] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
        else if (i >= 10 && i <= 14)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [6] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
        else if (i >= 15 && i <= 20)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [10] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
        else if (i >= 21 && i <= 27)
        {
            cardCentreY [i] = cardCentreY [15] + card [1].getHeight () / 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A `while-loop` or maybe `for-loop`?

Comment: How did you get each set of numbers? Assuming there's a pattern to it, just try to describe that pattern precisely, step by step; once you've done that, you can work on coding that algorithm up. But the first step is going from "here are a bunch of numbers I hard-coded" to "here's _why_ I picked those specific numbers."

Comment: Are you sure your code is right as the first 4 assignments have a different pattern to the rest.  Can you not see any pattern when looking the indexes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide a minimal working example, which makes it difficult test any possible solutions to make sure they do the same thing as your code. I prototyped a simple version in JavaScript instead of Java, which let me do some simple visualizations as a sanity-check that my loop works correctly. I'm assuming that you'll be able to translate the JavaScript logic back into Java without too much trouble.

Here is the loop (in JavaScript):

```
var x_row_base = 250; // You used 800 here
var y = 0;
var cards = Array(28);

// Set up card pyramid
for (var i = 0, row = 0; i < cards.length; row++) {
  var x = x_row_base;
  for (var col = 0; col < row; i++, col++) {
    cards[i] = make_card(i, row);
    // set x and y position
    cards[i].x = x;
    cards[i].y = y;
    // create links to "child" cards in next row
    if (i < 21) {
      cards[i].left_child_index = i + row;
      cards[i].right_child_index = i + row + 1;
    }
    // display the card
    draw_card(cards[i]);
    x += CARD_X_SPACING + CARD_X_PADDING;
  }
  y += CARD_Y_SPACING;
  x_row_base -= (CARD_X_SPACING + CARD_X_PADDING) / 2;
}
```

You can try it out using the snippet below ([or on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaoWen/fvp9tcbg/1/)). The parent/child card links are shown by changing the color of the child cards when you hover over the parent. Here is a screenshot what the JavaScript visualization looks like on my laptop:

[image]

```js
function draw_card(card) {
  var $card = $("<div/>");
  $card.text(card.label);
  $card.addClass('card');
  $card.css({
    'left': card.x,
    'top': card.y,
    'z-index': card.z
  });
  $card.appendTo($('#my_canvas'));
  card.rect = $card;
  // last row doesn't actually have children
  if (card.left_child_index) {
    $card.mouseover(function() {
      cards[card.left_child_index].rect.addClass("child");
      cards[card.right_child_index].rect.addClass("child");
    });
    $card.mouseout(function() {
      cards[card.left_child_index].rect.removeClass("child");
      cards[card.right_child_index].rect.removeClass("child");
    });
  }
}

function make_card(label, z) {
  return {
    label: label,
    z: z
  };
}

var CARD_X_PADDING = 4;
var CARD_X_SPACING = 50;
var CARD_Y_SPACING = 45;

var x_row_base = 250; // You used 800 here
var y = 0;
var cards = Array(28);

// Set up card pyramid
for (var i = 0, row = 0; i < cards.length; row++) {
  var x = x_row_base;
  for (var col = 0; col < row; i++, col++) {
    cards[i] = make_card(i, row);
    // set x and y position
    cards[i].x = x;
    cards[i].y = y;
    // create links to "child" cards in next row
    if (i < 21) {
      cards[i].left_child_index = i + row;
      cards[i].right_child_index = i + row + 1;
    }
    // display the card
    draw_card(cards[i]);
    x += CARD_X_SPACING + CARD_X_PADDING;
  }
  y += CARD_Y_SPACING;
  x_row_base -= (CARD_X_SPACING + CARD_X_PADDING) / 2;
}
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to replicate the pattern in the first loop:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int offset = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {
        offset += i;
        for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            card[index++].setPtrs(card[offset+j-1], card[offset+j]);
            System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", index++, offset+j-1, offset+j);
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

```
0 1 2
1 3 4
2 4 5
3 6 7
4 7 8
5 8 9
6 10 11
7 11 12
8 12 13
9 13 14
10 15 16
11 16 17
12 17 18
13 18 19
14 19 20
15 21 22
16 22 23
17 23 24
18 24 25
19 25 26
20 26 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the answer, because working this out yourself will make you a better programmer, but here is a bit of a starting point for you.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 5;
while (i < 21)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
  {
    card [i].setPtrs (card [k], card [k + 1]);
  }      
  j++;
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // x - co ords
 cardCentreX [0] = 800;
 cardCentreX [1] = 800 - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
 cardCentreX [2] = 800 + card [1].getWidth () / 2;

 int last_count = 1;
 int curr_count = 0;
 int last_card = 0;
 boolean special = false;

 for (int i=3; i<= 27; i++){
     if (special){
         cardCentreX [i] = cardCentreX [last_card] + card [1].getWidth () / 2;
         special = false;
     } else {
          last_card++;
          cardCentreX [i] = cardCentreX [last_card] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
          if (curr_count == last_count + 1){
              last_count = curr_count;
              curr_count = 0;
              special = true;
           }
     }
```

That should work. For the x-coordinates.
The idea is that you have a recurring special property every x+1 equations?
Where x is the last number of line you went through before reaching the special line.

Comment: there's no bool datatype in java.

Comment: Sorry, I meant boolean, bool is the c++ version

Answer (score 0):

This for loops presented are based on the pattern of numbers you have set out, if not clear use a print statement for variables to understand workings (provided in comment):

```
 static int j = 1;
for(int 1 = 0; i <21; i++){

card [i].setPtrs (card [j], card [j+1]);
  if((j+1)%4 == 0) j-1; 

  j+2;
  counter++;
// System.out.println("i = " +i +", j = " +j +", j+1=" +(j+1));
    }

    // set card X coords
static int k = 1, counter = 1; // counter is a variable used for reference

cardCentreX [0] = 800;
cardCentreX [1] = 800 - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
cardCentreX [2] = 800 + card [1].getWidth () / 2;


for(int i=3; i < 28; i++){
   cardCentreX [i] = cardCentreX [k] - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
   if((i - k) == (counter+1)){ 
      k++; // increment card centre index
      counter++; 
   }
 // System.out.println("i = " +i, +", k = " +k, + ", counter = " +counter);
}
```

Look at how i have shortened your code, you should be able to evaluate and shorten the last for loop on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
cardCentrecount [0] = 800;
cardCentrecount [1] = 800 - card [1].getWidth () / 2;
cardCentrecount [2] = 800 + card [1].getWidth () / 2;

    int count = 3;
    int term = 2;
    for ( int i=3, j=1; i<=27; i++,j++ ) {

    if ( (j-1) == term ) {
        cardCentrecount[i] = cardCentrecount[ --j ] + card[1].getWidth() / 2;
        term += count;
        count ++;
    }
    else
        cardCentrecount[i] = cardCentrecount[j] + card[1].getWidth() / 2;
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation around the code to explain why this will solve the OP's problem.